# Mysql import data status in elastic search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search in my application, my database has around 150k records. so when importing data from mysql to my application it takes minimum 20 minutes.How to check all data from mysql imported successfully in elastic search ? is there any command in elastic search to check this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Count API in elastisearch to check number of records.This is how you make a curl request

eg: curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_count'

This is the response you will get, the value in count will be number of records.

{"count":12963,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0}}

For more information you can check this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html